# Autoconf/Automake "configure.ac:2: option `−Wall' not recognized"

Tags: g++, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to start with autoconf / automake for a new project. To get started, I'm reading ["Using GNU Autotools"](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html) and trying to build the Hello-World-Tutorial.

The required files from page 96 (real Page=105 because it's a LaTeX-Presentation) `configure.ac`, `Makefile.am` and `src/Makefile.am` look exactly as stated in the document.

After that I tried:

```
$ autoreconf --install
configure.ac:2: option `−Wall' not recognized
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Well, it seems that automake doesn't like the second line:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([−Wall −Werror foreign])
```

Therefore I executed:

```
$ autoreconf -v --install
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
configure.ac:2: option `−Wall' not recognized
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

You can see easily that autoconf runs `automake --add-missing --copy --no-force` which I repeated with the verbose-option. And it only returns this:

```
$ automake -v --add-missing --copy --no-force 
automake: thread 0: reading autoconf --trace=_LT_AC_TAGCONFIG:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_ENABLE_MULTILIB:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_SILENT_RULES:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_INIT:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_COND_IF:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_FILES:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CANONICAL_TARGET:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_FC_SRCEXT:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CANONICAL_HOST:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_GNU_GETTEXT:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_LIBSOURCE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CANONICAL_BUILD:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=sinclude:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_PROG_CC_C_O:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_LINKS:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=m4_sinclude:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=LT_SUPPORTED_TAG:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_CONDITIONAL:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_HEADERS:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_MAINTAINER_MODE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=m4_include:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_COND_ELSE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_GNU_GETTEXT_INTL_SUBDIR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_COND_ENDIF:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_SUBST_TRACE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}%
configure.ac:2: option `−Wall' not recognized
```

Anybody an idea why this doesn't work? My impression is that none of my files are wrong...

I would like to use it for compiling C++ code for Linux and Windows (using mingw32-g++). Do you know any base where to start and what I have to pay attention for?

I'm on Ubuntu 9.10 64bit.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it's an encoding problem: the character `−` (that you used in front of `Wall`) is not the ASCII `-` character that you should be using.

Comment: Thx! damn, i've been sure to have typed it by hand... well... must have been something wrong with it though. regards